# A bit of a retread

Tags: english, language

Here are a series of clues to two-word phrases.

1. Anxious Sweets
2. Prize Storage
3. Tightly Packed Weapons
4. Fly Flavor
5. Container Cover
6. Boring Performer
7. Ominous Feeling
8. Dishonest Track
9. Spring Spud
10. Ardent Prima Donna
11. Headlining Tattletales
12. Decorated Decoration
13. Christmas Professional
14. Cheesy Hamilton
15. Prepared Advanced Math

All of the **words** in the answers share a one-word property. What are the answers, and what is the property?

If people like this puzzle enough, I'll do a similar one *with a twist*!

Comment: Ingenious!  Well done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

edit: Updated, my first try was wrong on 3/15 answers.

> 1. Anxious Sweets = stressed desserts
>  2. Prize Storage = reward drawer
>  3. Tightly Packed Weapons = snug guns
>  4. Fly Flavor = gnat tang
>  5. Container Cover = pot top
>  6. Boring Performer = drab bard
>  7. Ominous Feeling = doom mood
>  8. Dishonest Track = liar rail
>  9. Spring Spud = may yam
>  10. Ardent Prima Donna = avid diva
>  11. Headlining Tattletales = star rats
>  12. Decorated Decoration = laced decal
>  13. Christmas Professional = Noel Leon
>  14. Cheesy Hamilton = rennet tenner
>  15. Prepared Advanced Math = girt trig 
>  I'm not too sure about 12 - "laméd medal" (as in gold lamé) and "laced decal" both seem arguably correct, but tenuous enough that you might've intended a different answer...

And the quality that links these words is that they are

> palindromes

Comment: You're very close, but your property is incorrect. As a result, some of your answers are also incorrect, specifically 1, 3 and 9. As a bit of a clue, for clue 12, "laméd medal" is incorrect, but "laced decal" is correct.

Comment: To clarify, your property isn't incorrect so much as it is not specific enough.

Comment: Methinks they're supposed to read forward, then backwards. :)

Comment: Should be right now :)

Comment: It might be **mirrored** words. +1 for cracking it

Comment: The words themselves aren't palindromes, but you're close enough. =P The word I was looking for is emordnilap, but after a cursory google to add a link in this comment to a definition, I discovered that it's not a real word. Oh well!

Comment: Incidentally, kudos on the speed with which you solved this, I was sure 14 and 15 were going to cause problems!

Comment: @VictorHenry I think the word you were looking for was "semordnilap" - it's not technically a real word, but it's at least commonly recognized.